# How to print a histogram from a number list

Tags: python

Why does my code print `None` at the end? How to get rid of it?

```
def histogram(list1):
    for n in list1:
        output = " "
        times = n
        while times > 0:
          output += "*"
          times -= 1
        print(output)

print(histogram([1, 3, 5, 7, 18]))
```

I tried a `while` loop and a `for` loop, but they didn't help

Comment: What value does histogram return?

Answer (score 2):

Your histogram function is doing the printing, but does not return anything from the function, so printing its result prints nothing, or if you're evaluating in the interactive interpreter, you'll see `None`, which is the value returned from a Python function that has no explicit return.

Your `histogram` function should build up a string that can be printed.

```py
def histogram(list1):
    return '\n'.join('*' * n for n in list1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code outputs the following:

```
 *
 ***
 *****
 *******
 ******************
 None
```

This is because the function doesn't return anything (it did the printing itself), it implicitly returns `None` so the call `print(histogram[...])` prints "None" after everything printed by the histogram function call itself.

You have two options:

1. Just call `histogram(input)` and not print of it.
2. Adjust `histogram` to build up and return a string and print that result.

You probably want #2

One way to do this is the following:

```
def histogram(list1):
    return '\n'.join('*' * n for n in list1)
```

What you choose depends on context, namely what you need to use histogram for elsewhere, and whether you always want calls to the function to print immediately or if you want them to return strings to you that you could print or compare or even write to disk.